# How to pass parameter via submit input without javascript?

Tags: html, submit, forms

I have a form that contains multiple submit buttons. How can I pass a parameter submitting the form to find out which submit has been pressed? No JavaScript allowed.

Comment: Don't tag this with "JavaScript" if no JavaScript is allowed.
That language are you using, server-side?

Comment: I meant "What language are you using", typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 or more buttons like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButtonOne" value="Button One"/>
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButtonTwo" value="Button Two"/>
```

Check for the names of the buttons, in the submitted (POST) data.

In PHP for example, that would be:

```
if (isset($_POST['SubmitButtonOne'])){
    //Do something.
}elseif (isset($_POST['SubmitButtonTwo'])){
    //Do something.
}
```

Or, check for the submitted values:

```
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Button One"/>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Button Two"/>
```

```
switch ($_POST['formSubmit']) {
    case 'Button One':
        //Do something.
        break;
  case 'Button Two':
        //Do something else.
        break;
}
```

Comment: You're very welcome! Thanks for accepting this as the answer ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Only the button that submitted the form will be sent to the server. So just create multiple submit buttons with different names, and then check which button is present in the POST data.